# website hacked possible perl script on router?

Tags: perl

I dont know if this will be the right place to ask, and I dont know exactly how to phrase this in a way that will make sense. Im looking at a website for a customer in work and I am connected to the wifi I can see random references to Viagra thrown in between sentences on their website. They cant see it when they look from their own computers and I cant see it if Im using 3G on my phone but when I connect to the wifi I can see it then. I was told it could be perl script on their router so I wouldnt see anything suspicious in the source code. how can something like this be done?

Comment: This is not suitable for the perl-tag, which is only really about Perl programming. You should add some networking tags, the name of the webserver they use, etc. And you should probably elaborate on exactly what different output you get (along with source quotes with html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a transparent proxy which can alter the content of any request or response passing through it. Your question is incredibly vague, so I cannot provide much specific help, however you can read about [squid](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=squid%20http%20proxy%20transparent) (link is to a search heh) which is a http proxy which can perform such tasks.

One of the first things I would look at would be the [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) for the router. It may be that external requests are being routed through such a proxy while internal ones are not.